# C# lambda Join & Update

Tags: c#, linq, join, lambda

I use entity framework.
The class List is

```
class List
{
public string cid { get; set; }
public string type{ get; set; }
public string memo{ get; set; }
public DateTime sdate{ get; set; }
}
```

and count about 50.

I want join the table about members.
members's columns are:
id,cid,name,address

```
var result =
thelist.Where(w => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type)).Join(db.members,list => list.cid,member => member,(list,member) => list).ToList();
```

-> Not sure to work.

I want get the list record that cid in table members.
and update list's memo with members's name.

Can I do that by using lambda ??

Comment: you really shouldn't modify things in a lambda

Comment: Your code and your description of the code don't seem to match. It is not very clear what you're trying to do. Can you please clarify?

Comment: If I've got your join correct, it's this: `from w in thelist where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(w.type) join m in db.members on w.cid equals m select w`. Is that right?

Comment: What exact entity framework and what version? I wouldn't call a class List to avoid confusion with List<T>; surely you can think of a better , less bland/generic name. Public properties should begin with an uppercase letter. If you've named your props thus for eg Json serializing purposes you should note that most serializers have ways of specifying what Json attribute name to use so you don't have to tie your c# to crappy Json names. Example for newtonsoft `[JsonProperty("sdate")]public DateTime AppointmentDate{..}`

Comment: Have you mapped relationships between list and members? If not, you should. It'll make life much easier

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking to avoid SQL, sure. But you need to set up your table relations in a specific way.

You should define your keys and foreign keys in the class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public string cid { get; set; }
    public string type{ get; set; }
    public string memo{ get; set; }
    public DateTime sdate{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Members> {get;set;}
}

public class Members{
    public virtual Parent Parent {get;set;}
    [Key]
    public int id {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("Parent")] //This should match database table name
    public string cid {get;set;}
    //...other data types
}
```

You should mirror the database exactly in terms of variable names, nullability (if you have a nullable variable in the database, make sure it's nullable in the class: int -> int?), foreign keys should match.

Once you have everything set up in a neat way it's trivial to get the child table values connected to the parent:

```
//...

List<Parent> resultsWithChildren = _dbContext.Parent.Where(x => x.cid == "someid").Include(x => x.Members).ToList();
```

By adding "Include" EntityFramework will load all the tables it can automatically find a link to, which is why the relationship set up is important.

Then you can simply iterate through the data however you please. Every 'resultWithChildren' variable will have a corresponding 'Members' list.